# Module which is not a quotient of a product

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a non-zero commutative ring. We know that any $R$-module $M$ can be written as a quotient of a free module, e.g. $R^{(M)} \to M \to 0$ via $e_m \mapsto m$.

But is there an example of an $R$-module $M$ which is not a quotient of the product $R^J$ for any set $J$ ? This can't work if $M$ is finitely generated, of course (take $J$ to be any set of generators).
I guess there should be an example : in general it is difficult to construct morphisms from a product to a given module (but easier from a *coproduct* to a given module).

Comment: My question arised in the following context: I wanted to study $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M',M)$ (for some module $M'$), so if we had some set $J$ with an exact sequence $0 \to K \to R^J \to M \to 0$, then we could consider (this is where we need $R^J$ to be a _product_) $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M', R^J) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(M', R)^{J}$.

Comment: (For the zero ring it depends on whether you ask your modules to be unital, i.e. $1\cdot x = x$, in which case there is only one module over the zero ring : $0$)

How about a coproduct ? Say $R^{(I)}$ for some infinite $I$ ? (I don't know if that works, I haven't been able to prove it)

Comment: If $R$ is a field, there is no such modules. But for $R = \Bbb Z$, accodring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slender_group, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187250/every-free-abelian-group-is-slender-why, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187249/every-homomorphism-from-the-baer-specker-group-into-a-slender-group-factors-thro, any uncountable free abelian group $M$ has no surjective morphism $\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N} \to M$ (because such a morphism factors through the countable group $\Bbb Z^n$ for some $n$), but there might be some surjection $\Bbb Z^J \to M$ for a big set $J$.